# How to handle formData with Angular-Payments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stripe-payments

I'm making use of [Angular-Payments](https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments) in my AngularApp. After passing all the data to Stripe, I would like to store the users credit cards last 4 digits on my server. I'm having trouble accessing the form data so that I can get the last 4 digits from the card number.

My code is as follows

html:

```
      <form stripe-form="handleStripe" role="form" ng-if="authenticated" name="takeMoneyForm" ng-submit="takeMoney(takeMoneyForm, model)">
            <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card_name">

            <label class='control-label'>Card Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card_number" ng-model="number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" payments-type-model="type" ng-class="takeMoneyForm.number.$card.type">
      </form>
```

Controller code to accept & submit form:

```
  $scope.takeMoney = function(formData, model){
    $scope.handleStripe = function(status, response){
      if(response.error) {
        alert("Error happened")
      } else {
        var dataModel = {
          email: model.email,
          profile: {
            stripe_token: response.id,
            last_4_digits: "how can I get the cards last 4 digits here??",
            stripe_id: 'df'
          }
        }
        djangoAuth.takeMoney(dataModel)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: looks like `ng-if` is messing by creating child scope..

Comment: My data is being submitted fine. I just need access to the form data inside of `handleStripe` so that I may extract last 4 digits of CC

Answer (score 0):

```
  last_4_digits:  response.card.last4
```

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js?

You can also pull the information on your server using the token.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#tokens

Answer (score 0):

Sending the token to Stripe directly doesn't actually charge the card. To charge the user's card, you have to send the token to a script on your server, which Stripe provides various libraries for. It's this step that allows you to rip out whatever data was in the token and then save the details to your server and then send the charge to Stripe according the the API.

Here is the page that give examples of the server-side scripts for this step: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges